# Iterate over a file with ObjectInputStream

Tags: java

I cannot iterate over a file with this 3 strings more than once. I can only get this strings in first loop iteration.

With this method I check if an username and a password are equal with data stored in file and encoded with Caesar Cipher

```
private boolean confirmCredentials(String username, String password) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    boolean confirm = false;
    try {
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(loginDataPath));
        do {
            String username2 = (String) ois.readObject();
            String password2 = (String) ois.readObject();
            String localShift = (String) ois.readObject();

            String s = CaeserCipher.decode(localShift, shift);
            String p = CaeserCipher.decode(password2, Integer.parseInt(s));
            confirm = username2.equals(username) && p.equals(password);
        } while(!confirm);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw e;
    } catch(IOException e) {
    } finally {
        try {
            ois.close();
        } catch(IOException e) {
        }
    }
    return confirm;
}
```

I'm writing data in file like this:

```
public boolean setCredentials(String username, String password) throws IOException {
    String localShift;
    if(validate(username, password)) {
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
        try {
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(loginDataPath, true));

            Random randomGenerator = new Random();
            int random = randomGenerator.nextInt(26 + 1);

            password = CaeserCipher.encode(password, random);
            localShift = CaeserCipher.encode(String.valueOf(random), shift);

            oos.writeObject(username);
            oos.writeObject(password);
            oos.writeObject(localShift);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            oos.close();
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using an object stream and not simply a `FileReader` and `FileWriter`? You could even just use utility methods from `Files` to read/write. I don't see a purpose for using object streams here.

Answer (score -1):

Well...how many times do you think you need to read over the file and what on earth for (you don't specify)? In my opinion, your decryption should be handled **only** when the User Name matches to what is read in from file rather than decoding every password and **localShift** encountered.

If the password confirmation fails then continue reading until another instance of the same name is encountered within the file (if any):

```
private boolean confirmCredentials(String username, String password) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    boolean confirm = false;
    try {
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(loginDataPath));
        do {
            String username2 = (String) ois.readObject();
            String password2 = (String) ois.readObject();
            String localShift = (String) ois.readObject();

            // Is this the supplied User Name?
            if (username2.equals(username)) {
                // Yes it is so lets decode the necesssities and
                // confirm if the supplied password is correct.
                String s = CaeserCipher.decode(localShift, shift);
                String p = CaeserCipher.decode(password2, Integer.parseInt(s));
                if (p.equals(password)) {
                    confirm = true;
                }
            }
        } while (!confirm);
    } 
    catch (EOFException ex) {
        // The ObjectInputStream.readObject() method will never 
        // return null to indicate that it has reached the end 
        // of file, it does however throw an EOFException when 
        // the end of the file is reached. We simply catch this 
        // exception and do nothing with it.
    } 
    catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } 
    finally {
        try {
            if (ois != null) {
                ois.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return confirm;
}
```

Comment: `available()` is not a test for end of stream. See the Javadoc.

Comment: So true @EJP. Thank you for pointing that out. I have made the necessary corrections to my answer.